# A problem about a equivelant representation of a distance of measures.

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem**:

**For two probability measures  and  on the real line , the total variation distance is defined as**

$$
‖ − ‖_{TV} = \sup \{\mathit{\mu}(C) - \mathit{\nu}(C) \colon C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} ,
$$

**where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{C}(\mathit{\mu}, \mathit{\nu})$ be the space of couplings of the probability measures $\mathit{\mu}$ and $\mathit{\nu}$, i.e., the space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ valued random variables $(X, Y)$ defined on some (not necessarily same) probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathit{\mu}$ and $\mathit{\nu}$, respectively. It can be shown that**

\begin{equation*}
‖\mathit{\mu} − \mathit{\nu}‖_{{TV}} = \inf \{\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \colon (X, Y) \in \mathcal{C}(\mathit{\mu}, \mathit{\nu})\} .
\end{equation*}

**For simplicity, we may assume that $\mathit{\mu}$ and $\mathit{\nu}$ are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.**

I figue out that
$$
‖\mathit{\mu} − \mathit{\nu}‖_{{TV}} \leq \inf \{\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \colon (X, Y) \in \mathcal{C}(\mathit{\mu}, \mathit{\nu})\}.
$$
And the key to gain the other side is to construct a $\mathbb{P}$ s.t.
$$
\mathit{\mu}(C) − \mathit{\nu}(C) = \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y).
$$
But how?

Comment: If you're still looking for the answer, a proof can be found at the end of [this blog post](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2010/10/14/back-to-basics-total-variation-distance/)